# Isoperimetrics question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Here's an Algebra 2 problem that has been giving me fits.

The question is: A 50-inch length of string is cut and one length is formed into a circle and the other into a square. Where should you cut the string so that the sum of the areas is a minimum?

I was able to get a quadratic function and find the minimum using the vertex formula (and by differentiating to get where the slope = 0). It comes out to be roughly 22 and 28 inches for each shape. My question is more of an intuition problem.

I had been told that the greatest area that can be made from a fixed perimeter is a circle. Assuming that's true, why wouldn't you want to devote all 50 inches to make the square? (or at least devote an infinitesimal amount of string to make the circle?

What am I missing? (What is wrong with my intuition?) Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, and to minimize, my intuition tells me I should devote all 50 inches to the other shape, not the circle.. hence my confusion because mathematically the minimum is in between

Comment: I missread your argument. By the result you are quoting is better to have 2 squares instead of a circle and a square. Now, what is better one 50in square or 2 25in squares?

Comment: No, by the premise of the problem you have to have one circle and one square. The only question is how much string you use for the square, and how much you use for the circle. My intuition says you should use the whole string for the square. But the math says otherwise.

Comment: My argument is that it is better to split into two pieces that just one! So thats why your logic fails.